# Controlling parallelism when deploying flink kuberbetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

Not able to understand how flink is calculating the parallelism.
Here is my yaml.

1. If I comment our taskManager.replicas then I get parallelism of 2. This is understandable because job.parallelism is 2.
2. But if I uncomment taskManager.replicas then I get parallelism of 10. Not able to understand how is this calculated.
3. I am checking parallelism on flink UI.

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: stream-ingest
spec:
  restartNonce: 123
  image: public.ecr.aws/gsbots/genie-analytics-stream-ingest:20230515a
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  flinkVersion: v1_16
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "5"
    parallelism.default: "3"
    state.backend.type: rocksdb
    state.backend: rocksdb
    state.backend.incremental: "false"
    state.checkpoint-storage: filesystem
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://analytics-prod-storage-2021-12-05/crystalball/checkpoints
    state.savepoints.dir: s3://analytics-prod-storage-2021-12-05/crystalball/savepoints
    execution.checkpointing.interval: "600000"
    rest.flamegraph.enabled: "false"
    metrics.reporters: prom
    metrics.reporter.prom.port: "9250-9270"
    metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
    env.java.opts: >-
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
  serviceAccount: flink
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flink-main-container
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: genie-analytics-flink-env-cm
        volumeMounts:
        - name: configs
          mountPath: "/opt/app/conf"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: configs
        configMap:
          name: genie-analytics-flink-files-cm

  jobManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 2048m
    podTemplate:
      metadata:
        name: flink-job-manager
        labels:
          app: job-manager
      spec:

  taskManager:
    replicas: 2
    resource:
      cpu: 16
      memory: 128gb
    podTemplate:
      metadata:
        name: flink-task-manager
        labels:
          app: task-manager
      spec:
        affinity:
          nodeAffinity:
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              preference:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: high-iops1
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - "yes"
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/usrlib/flinkStreamIngest-1.0.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: savepoint
    savepointTriggerNonce: 124
```

Mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

- I think it's because the number of task manager replicas overrides the job parallelism.
- According the [Flink Kubernetes Operator Ref Spec](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-release-1.6/docs/custom-resource/reference/#taskmanagerspec), if you define a number of replicas, then it will take precedence over the job's parallelism.
- Since you'll have 2 task manager replicas, each having 5 task slots, you'll end up with 10 task slots.
- [Assuming each task slot can run a parallel instance of the job graph, (which is often the case)](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#task-slots-and-resources), you'll end up with a parallelism of 10.